# A Field Contained in All Fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, splitting-field

I've been thinking about subfield lattices. Textbook always ask about a extension $F/\mathbb{Q}$ and ask to draw the lattice and ask questions based on that. But what if we go the other way? Say $F/\mathbb{Q}$ is an extension of degree $n$. We can draw it's lattice of subfields. Say it has a subfield $F'$. $F'$ can appear as a subfield of other fields $L$. So being told that you have $F'$ means you can't know that this came from a field $F$.

But then I thought about counterexamples. It wasn't too hard to show that you can create infinitely many fields $L/F'/\mathbb{Q}$ such that $L/\mathbb{Q}$ has degree $d$ so that this proves knowing $F'$ appears in the lattice does not tell you "anything" about $F$. [I mean, you can get some information about $F$, either degree or discriminant, etc.] But can you take this farther?

**Q:** So given an extension $F'/\mathbb{Q}$ of degree $k$, can $F'$ be a subfield of all fields $F/\mathbb{Q}$ of degree $n$, where $n$ is divisible by $k$?

The answer should definitely be no. I feel like this should be easy to show but I couldn't think of an easy argument. I know you have to be careful because from the stuff I did in the other direction, there are infinitely many fields $F$ with degree $n$ that do contain $F'$ as a subfield. But this should not be all fields of degree $d$. There should still be infinitely many left. Is there a proof for this?

I also couldn't figure out what happens if you specified more than one subfield in the lattice. Like if you have $F'$ and $F''$ instead. Or generally, a whole finite collection of fields in the lattice, are there still infinitely many fields with degree $n$ that do not contain these fields in their lattice of subfields?

Comment: Given a field extension $K/\Bbb{Q}$ take $\alpha$ such that $K=\Bbb{Q}(\alpha)$, take an integer $d$ such that the minimal polynomial of $d\alpha$ is $f\in \Bbb{Z}[x]_{monic}$, let $D = Disc(f)$. Then for a prime $p> D$ and every $n$ you'll have that $x^n-p$ is Eisenstein at the prime ideals of $\Bbb{Z}[\alpha d]$ above $p$, so that $x^n-p\in K[x]$ is irreducible.

Comment: @reuns That clearly shows that $L_p= \mathbb{Q}(x^n - p)$ is a field of degree $n$ and that there are infinitely many fields $L_p$ of degree $n$. But why is it that every one of the fields (or at least infinitely many of them) do not also contain $F'$?

Comment: I meant $K=F'$. Then $x^n-p$ stays irreducible over $F'$, in particular $[F'(p^{1/n}):\Bbb{Q}]$ is larger than $[\Bbb{Q}(p^{1/n}):\Bbb{Q}]$ so you can't have $\Bbb{Q}(p^{1/n})=F'(p^{1/n})$ which would be the case if $F'\subset \Bbb{Q}(p^{1/n})$.

Comment: Many ways to get there. One way is to construct a polynomial $f(x)\in\Bbb{Q}[x]$ of degree  $n$ such that the Galois group $G=S_n$. If $\alpha$ is a root of $f(x)$, then $F=\Bbb{Q}(\alpha)$ is a degree $n$ extension, and Galois theory tells us that there simply are no fields strictly between $F$ and $\Bbb{Q}$. This is because $Stab_G(\alpha)\simeq S_{n-1}$ is a maximal subgroup of $S_n$.